# Using hscroll to scroll groupbox

Tags: c#, scrollbar

I have a `WINFORM` in which I have groupbox which dynamically displays buttons, as I am not sure how many buttons will be there, so if buttons are more then the horizontal size of groupbox rest of buttons gets invisible, so I want to use `Hscrollbar` to scroll through all buttons.

But I am not sure how to use it, so can you please assist me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `GroupBox.AutoSize = true` then the control will fit it size to the content. But if you don't want group box to growth, then put your group box into the `Panel`. Then set `Panel.AutoScroll = true`. Now if radio buttons impose on group box to growth, the panel size will not changed, but appropriate scroll bars will appear.